# Passing JWT to +page.server.js with Auth.js SvelteKit

Tags: javascript, jwt, svelte, sveltekit, next-auth

I am just learning SvelteKit and I have encountered a problem.
I am creating a login system using `Auth.js` for SvelteKit. I have never dealt with authentication so not everything is intuitive to me

I would like that when a user logs in through a provider, e.g. Github, a JWT would be returned which contains only the user ID. This ID would then be used to find the user in the database and display their data.

It could be described like this:

User logs in -> SvelteKitAuth() returns a JWT with the user ID -> User goes to /dashboard -> +page.server.js retrieves user data from the database based on the ID from the JWT -> Data is displayed

```
async function authorization({ event, resolve }) {
    if (event.url.pathname.startsWith('/article')) {
        const token = event.cookies.get('next-auth.session-token');
        const decoded = await decode({ token, secret: SVELTEAUTH_SECRET });
        console.log(decoded);
        if (!token) {
            throw redirect(303, '/auth?redirectSource=articleView');
        }
    }

    return resolve(event);
}

export const handle = sequence(
    SvelteKitAuth({
        providers: [GitHub({ clientId: GITHUB_ID, clientSecret: GITHUB_SECRET })],
        jwt: true,
        secret: SVELTEAUTH_SECRET,
        session: { strategy: 'jwt' },
        callbacks: {
            async jwt({ token, account, profile }) {
                // Persist the OAuth access_token and or the user id to the token right after signin
                if (account) {
                    token.userId = profile.id;
                }
                return token;
            }
        }
    }),
    authorization
);
```

I currently have this code. My problem is that I don't know how to pass JWT to `+page.server.js`, and consequently `+page.svelte`. `console.log(decoded);` returns the following.:

```
{
  name: ` zerakot`,
  email: '********',
  picture: 'https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/49678485?v=4',
  sub: '49678485',
  userId: 49678485,
  iat: 1695501797,
  exp: 1698093797,
  jti: '48a73079-bcba-46e4-851e-df5e7a43f089'
}
```

so the JWT is encoded correctly. Is my approach even correct? Is passing JWT to `+page.svelte.js` correct?

**Edit:**
I found this solution:

```
async function authorization({ event, resolve }) {
    if (event.url.pathname.startsWith('/article')) {
        const token = event.cookies.get('next-auth.session-token');

        if (!token) {
            throw redirect(303, '/auth?redirectSource=articleView');
        }
        event.locals.token = token;
    }
    return resolve(event);
}
```

It allows me to save the JWT and read it elsewhere. However, is this a good approach? Should I read the token from the cookies?

Comment: What you should do is pass the token to your backend to verify the signature (in the header) and then claims like issuer (isd), audience (aud) and expiry (exp) at the very least before trusting any data within it.  Just read the cookie between pages.

Comment: Could you explain exactly what you mean?

Comment: Please read: https://auth0.com/docs/secure/tokens/json-web-tokens/validate-json-web-tokens or let me know what exact bit is unclear :)